# Passing arrays from C to Fortran without knowing the size?

Tags: c, arrays, fortran

I'm trying to pass a 3d dynamic arrays from C to Fortran. For example, the first time I call the function I use

```
 extern "C" Fun_(double X[], double Y[], double Z[],
                 int *Nx, int *Ny, int *Nz,
                 double F[][20][20]);
```

The second  time I have to change it to

```
extern "C" Fun_(double X[], double Y[], double Z[],
                int *Nx, int *Ny, int *Nz,
                 double F[][10][40]);
```

and so on. The main code is

```
int main() {
char path[500],id_type[3];
char *dir_path, *file_path;      
Nx=10000,Ny=20,Nz=20; ----> or Ny=10,Nz=40;                                       
double X[Nx], Y[Ny], Z[Nz];
double F[Nx][20][20] --- > or F[Nx][10][40];
....}
```

The array changes 446 times. So, I have to change its size dynamically. Any suggestions? Thanks

The  Fortran code is pretty long but here is the relevant part

```
SUBROUTINE  Fun(X,Y,Z,Nx,Ny,Nz,F)
integer :: Nx,Ny,Nz,inx,iny,inz
real(8) :: F(Nx,Ny,Nz)
real(8) :: X(Nx),Y(Ny),Z(Nz)
....
```

Comment: Work with and pass a 1-D array, and figure out the indexing yourself?

Comment: I don't know how to pass a 1D array and convert it in a 3D array inside Fortran

Comment: Given your Fortran procedure looks like it is called `Fun_` I imagine you aren't using the C interoperability capacity on the Fortran side.  Either way, can you show the Fortran procedure's interface?  And how free are you to change the C and Fortran?

Comment: @francescalus I included a few lines from my Fotran code.

Comment: What is your `F[Nx][20][20]`? Show the actual code, not something describing it. Is it a jagged array? Those are not compatible with Fortran.

Comment: @VladimirF What? This is the code I'm using. In fact, F[Nx][20][20] should be F[Nx][Ny][Nz] but if I try  to define the array this way, the compiler complains:  "error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token". I'm  passing  Nx, Ny,Nz. So, Fortran knows the size of the array all the time.

Comment: I am asking how do you allocate it. You said it is a dynamic atray. Do you use `malloc()`? If yes, how? BTW try `const int Nx=`.

Comment: @VladimirF No, right now the array is not a dynamic one. So, it is defined as double F[Nx][20][20].

Comment: The intrinsic module (Fortran 2003+) `iso_c_binding` contains named constants such as `C_DOUBLE`, procedures such as `c_f_pointer`, and much more. In C arrays always start with index 0 whereas in Fortran they start by default with 1. In Fortran you can easily reset the default to 0, whereas offsetting C pointers is more error prone. Thus, an array declaration `real(C_DOUBLE) :: foo(0:n-1,0:m-1)` in Fortran matches `double foo[m][n]` in C and accessing the element `foo(i,j)` matches `foo[j][i].` Can you supply us with a short program to illustrate what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

*Caveat:* It's been a long time since I did fortran, but this is what I came up with.

The variable length arrays seem easy enough. But, C uses row-major order for its 2D [and higher] arrays. But, Fortran uses column-major order. So, either the C code or the Fortran code will need to be aware of this.

I've created two subroutines: `subx` which is native Fortran, column-major order. And, `suby` which is C compatible, row-major order.

Also, some test output is below. Because the arrays are created as C-compatible, row-major, only `suby` produces the expected output.

*Side note:* One of my references for this was: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html

---

Here's the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void subx_(int *,int *,int *);
void suby_(int *,int *,int *);

void
dotest(int Dy,int Dx)
{
    int val = 0;

    int arr[Dy][Dx];

    for (int y = 0;  y < Dy;  ++y) {
        for (int x = 0;  x < Dx;  ++x)
            arr[y][x] = val++;
    }

    subx_(&Dy,&Dx,&arr[0][0]);
    suby_(&Dy,&Dx,&arr[0][0]);
}

int
main(void)
{

    printf("testing ...\n");
    dotest(3,4);
    dotest(6,5);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the Fortran code:

```
! this uses column-major order -- _not_ C compatible
subroutine subx(Dy,Dx,arr)
integer :: Dy,Dx
integer :: arr(Dy,Dx)
integer :: x,y

    write(*,700) ""
700 format (a)
    write(*,800) "subx: Dy=",Dy," Dx=",Dx
800 format (a,i4,a,i4)

    do y = 1, Dy
        do x = 1, Dx

    write(*,900) "subx ",x,y,arr(y,x)
900 format (a,i8,i8,i8)

        end do
    end do

end subroutine subx

! this uses row-major order -- _is_ C compatible
subroutine suby(Dy,Dx,arr)
integer :: Dy,Dx
integer :: arr(Dx,Dy)
integer :: x,y

    write(*,700) ""
700 format (a)
    write(*,800) "suby: Dy=",Dy," Dx=",Dx
800 format (a,i4,a,i4)

    do y = 1, Dy
        do x = 1, Dx

    write(*,900) "suby ",x,y,arr(x,y)
900 format (a,i8,i8,i8)

        end do
    end do

end subroutine suby
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
testing ...

subx: Dy=   3 Dx=   4
subx        1       1       0
subx        2       1       3
subx        3       1       6
subx        4       1       9
subx        1       2       1
subx        2       2       4
subx        3       2       7
subx        4       2      10
subx        1       3       2
subx        2       3       5
subx        3       3       8
subx        4       3      11

suby: Dy=   3 Dx=   4
suby        1       1       0
suby        2       1       1
suby        3       1       2
suby        4       1       3
suby        1       2       4
suby        2       2       5
suby        3       2       6
suby        4       2       7
suby        1       3       8
suby        2       3       9
suby        3       3      10
suby        4       3      11

subx: Dy=   6 Dx=   5
subx        1       1       0
subx        2       1       6
subx        3       1      12
subx        4       1      18
subx        5       1      24
subx        1       2       1
subx        2       2       7
subx        3       2      13
subx        4       2      19
subx        5       2      25
subx        1       3       2
subx        2       3       8
subx        3       3      14
subx        4       3      20
subx        5       3      26
subx        1       4       3
subx        2       4       9
subx        3       4      15
subx        4       4      21
subx        5       4      27
subx        1       5       4
subx        2       5      10
subx        3       5      16
subx        4       5      22
subx        5       5      28
subx        1       6       5
subx        2       6      11
subx        3       6      17
subx        4       6      23
subx        5       6      29

suby: Dy=   6 Dx=   5
suby        1       1       0
suby        2       1       1
suby        3       1       2
suby        4       1       3
suby        5       1       4
suby        1       2       5
suby        2       2       6
suby        3       2       7
suby        4       2       8
suby        5       2       9
suby        1       3      10
suby        2       3      11
suby        3       3      12
suby        4       3      13
suby        5       3      14
suby        1       4      15
suby        2       4      16
suby        3       4      17
suby        4       4      18
suby        5       4      19
suby        1       5      20
suby        2       5      21
suby        3       5      22
suby        4       5      23
suby        5       5      24
suby        1       6      25
suby        2       6      26
suby        3       6      27
suby        4       6      28
suby        5       6      29
```

Comment: [Though I've upvoted, I feel the comments in the Fortran code (column- vs row-major) might be a bit confusing for OP...

Comment: @roygvib The terms are also in the text above. The tutorial link has an explanation of the terms, with diagrams, and [I just realized] `do` and `for` loop examples for traversal. I think OP can use that [along with the code--their's and mine]. Originally, I thought the job was done when the fortran compiled (i.e. if it compiled, it understood VLAs), but, then, I noticed the array dimension issue from the tutorial, so I decided to further prove it out by writing a sample diagnostic, just to be sure.